# SQL and JS, how i can read text from SQL (discord)

Tags: javascript, sql

I'm writing code for Discord, this is my code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mydb"
});

    var name = 'name';
    var id = '1';
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = ? OR id = ?';
    con.query(sql, [name, id], function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
});
```

The code works and it shows me what I have in the table, now I want to design it nicely, and I have the following design:

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + [name])) {
           const logo = ''
           const embed = new MessageEmbed()
               .setTitle("name is: " + [name])
 }
  message.channel.send(embed);
});
```

Now it's working.
But my problem is that I want it to be offered to me from SQL.

This means that instead of the name I have listed every name I want I want to get results from SQL in case there is no result that will show me an error message.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: If you are able to console.log your result and gives the desired result set, then just do a `return result;` instead. A normal approach would be to have this query function that returns the result (or error) in another file (acting like your own API), then in the front, you use a fetch method to get the result. This is the classical way of handling this type of logic.

Comment: Ok but how can I get someone to write something in a chat it will show him the table I have in the table I have a number of values, and I want every time it looks for an existing value and shows it to me